# how to traverse a file in python and c++ in backward way? And also store data in backward (bottom to top) way?

Tags: c++, python

Suppose i want to store 3 lines in a file both in python and C++ . 
I want to store it like this

```
aaa
bbb 
ccc ..
```

But i am giving `ccc` input first then `bbb` then `aaa`. How will I traverse the file from bottom to top and also store from bottom to top/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't obvious from the title and question whether you want to store to a file, load from a file, or both, so I'll cover both cases:

## Reading

If it's OK to load it all into memory at once (in Python):

```
list(reversed(list(open('foo.txt'))))
```

Otherwise, it gets a lot more difficult. Processing a file backwards requires that you read blocks of data a time from the end, scanning backwards through each block for newline marker, and stitching things back together at block boundaries.

## Writing

If the data all fit in memory at once, put the numbers into a list (in Python):

```
open('foo.txt', 'w').writelines(reversed(data))
```

If `data` is an iterable, replace it with `list(data)`.

If the data doesn't fit in memory (e.g., you have some generator that spits out a ton of data), the problem will be much harder. The simplest solution that comes to mind is to just push the data into a sqlite database and then copy it into the file. Or you might just find it easier to use the data directly from sqlite.

Comment: You'd need a massive file - many 100s of MB on today's low-end machines - before you couldn't load it this way

Comment: And how exactly does this involve writing to a file?

Comment: Ignacio, at first I thought I'd completely misread the question, but then I realised that the title explicitly asks about traversing a file, which coloured my reading of the question. I've edited the answer to cover both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a `collections.deque`. Afaik those things are optimised for insertion at one of their endpoints, so you could read your file as it is and fill the lines into a `deque` object with its `appendleft` method ... just a thought. No idea how efficient that would be. :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the lines to be generated at the beginning of your linear structure (`list`, `vector<string>`) each time, then iterate your structure from beginning to end.

Comment: Please don't suggest inserting at the front of a vector its  O(n)

Comment: Doesn't have to be a `vector<>`. Any linear structure that allows insertion at the beginning works.